# Can you run pgAdmin 4 v3 as desktop app?

Tags: pgadmin-4

Can you run pgAdmin 4 v3 as desktop application?

If yes. Is there anyone that could post simple guid for this?

I read docs from [pgAdmin_docs](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/3.x/desktop_deployment.html) site but i didn't understand a thing.

Comment: They have changed it. It now runs on your device in your browser instead of previously not running in your browser, that's all. It does the same stuff. For what I do I can't see any difference except that it's running in Chrome

Comment: My job is programming (web apps) and most of the time i have all browsers open (chrome, firefox, edge, ..) with multiple tabs. What annoys me is to have pgAdmin somewhere in that tab forest. I'd rather have it as desktop app.

Comment: They (PGadmin team) seem very happy that they have cleared a lot of bugs but they have caused a bit of grief as well. I find Squirrel SQL more suitable for my needs and it's a desktop app, give it a try. I only use PGadmin occaisionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They changed it starting from pgAdmin 4 v2. So, if you go back to v1.x you will be able to use it as desktop app.

Comment: Yes i know that but i'am hoping there will be option for question above.

Comment: There is also a fork of pgAdmin 3 with long term support, it’s what I use and it works very well: https://www.openscg.com/bigsql/pgadmin3/